# Decreasing function depending in parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Consider :

- $\alpha$ , $\lambda$ and $\rho$ $\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\alpha$ $\geq$ - $\frac{1}{2}$
- $a=\alpha$ + $\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{\lambda^2}{2(\alpha+1)}$
- a function $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$   ,  $x>0$
- $f$ is decreasing to $2\rho$

  ie:  $f$ is decreasing and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 2\rho\;
   \forall x > 0.$$

Consider a function $H:$ $$H(x) = \frac{a}{x} - \frac{1}{2}f(x) - b\ , \forall x > 0.$$

I need to know:

- in which cases $$\exists\ c \in \mathbb{R}\  : H(x) < c\ , \forall x > 0.$$
- in these cases what are the values of $c$ ?

Thanks.

**Update**

$$f(x) = \frac{2 \alpha + 1}{x} + \beta(x)\ , \forall x > 0.$$

where $\beta$ is a function and $\beta(0)=0$

Comment: We know almost nothing about $f(x)$. Don't we know about $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$?

Comment: @mathlove : we can take all  cases of these limit ( +infinity , positif or negatif real ) .for each case we check the H function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that
$$H(x)\lt c$$
is equivalent to
$$f(x)\gt \frac{2\alpha +1}{x} - \frac{\lambda^2}{\alpha+1}-2c\tag1$$

- Case 1 : If $\alpha=-\frac 12$, then $(1)$ becomes
  $$f(x)\gt - 2\lambda^2-2c\tag2$$If $f(x)\gt 2\rho$ for all $x\gt 0$, then in order to have $(2)$ for all $x\gt 0$, it is sufficient to have
  $$2\rho\ge -2\lambda^2-2c,$$
  i.e.
  $$c\ge -\lambda^2-\rho$$If $f(x)=2\rho$ for some $x\gt 0$, then in order to have $(2)$ for all $x\gt 0$, it is sufficient to have
  $$2\rho\gt -2\lambda^2-2c,$$
  i.e.
  $$c\gt -\lambda^2-\rho$$
- Case 2 : If $\alpha\gt -\frac 12$, then we have
  $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=+\infty$$
  where $g(x)$ is the RHS of $(1)$. So, in order to have $(1)$ for all $x\gt 0$, at least we have to have
  $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$$However, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$ does not necessarily imply that $(1)$ holds for all $x\gt 0$.

---

*Conclusion* :

- If $\alpha=-\frac 12$ and $f(x)\gt 2\rho$ for all $x\gt 0$, and $c\ge -\lambda^2-\rho$, then $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$.
- If $\alpha=-\frac 12$ and $f(x)\gt 2\rho$ for all $x\gt 0$, and $c\lt -\lambda^2-\rho$, then there exists an $x\gt 0$ such that $H(x)\ge c$.
- If $\alpha=-\frac 12$ and $f(x)=2\rho$ for some $x\gt 0$, and $c\gt -\lambda^2-\rho$, then $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$.
- If $\alpha=-\frac 12$ and $f(x)=2\rho$ for some $x\gt 0$, and $c\le -\lambda^2-\rho$, then there exists an $x\gt 0$ such that $H(x)\ge c$.
- If $\alpha\gt -\frac 12$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\gamma$ where $\gamma\in\mathbb R$, then there exists an $x\gt 0$ such that $H(x)\ge c$.
- If $\alpha\gt -\frac 12$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$, then whether $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$ depends on the form of $f(x)$. For example, if $f(x)=\frac{2\alpha+1}{x}+2\rho$ and $c\gt -\rho-\frac{\lambda^2}{2(\alpha+1)}$, then $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$. But if $f(x)=\frac{2\alpha+1}{\sqrt x}+2\rho$, then there does not exist $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $H(x)\lt c$ for all $x\gt 0$.)

---

**Added** :

If $f(x) = \frac{2 \alpha + 1}{x} + \beta(x)$ where $\beta(0)=0$, then we see that $H(x)\lt c$ is equivalent to
$$\beta(x)\gt - \frac{\lambda^2}{\alpha+1}-2c$$

Whether $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$ depends on the form of $\beta(x)$.

For example, if $\beta(x)=2\rho-\frac{2\rho}{x+1}$ and $\rho\lt 0$, and $c\ge -\rho-\frac{\lambda^2}{2(\alpha+1)}$, then $H(x)\lt c$ holds for all $x\gt 0$.

But if $\beta(x)=\begin{cases}0&(x=0)\\2\rho-\frac 1x&(x\gt 0)\end{cases}$ and $\alpha\gt 0$, then there does not exist $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $H(x)\lt c$ for all $x\gt 0$.

(I have not been able to find such a function $\beta(x)$ where $\beta(x)$ is continuous.)

Comment: thanks @mathlove, can you see my update please, i added some extra information

Comment: @Lamloumi Afif : I've added some explanations.